# Auth0 Guest user login and Rest API login

Tags: authentication, auth0

Lately I started looking into PoC with Auth0 for our use case where we want to allow users to login with Google and Facebook, also want Guest user to login and access our API and once guest user choose to login with Google and Facebook then we can link guest user so that their data will be served once logout.

Here's the things which I am to able to do till now with PoC:

- Able to Login with Google and Facebook through client App.
- Access authenticated API after getting bearer token from client App.

Things which still need to do, I tried to search but couldn't found good resource:

- I want user to login as Guest user and latter if they want they can login with Google/FB and link their account.
- Also, I am looking into Rest login API in Auth0 so that we can hit login API after getting access token from Google/FB and register user into Auth0 and get the token for API access.

It would be great if anyone help me on above two points. Thanks!

Comment: I was running into the same issue and it seems like there's no solution? It's just something that Auth0 does not do or help you with? Or did you find something?

Comment: Hi @IOrlandoni, I haven't found any way to do this with Auth0 as we move to Azure AD B2C for authentication and authorization. Please let me know if you found anything